# What are the differences between porpoise; bounced; and nose-pointed-down landings?

Tags: landing

I have read some articles, and to tell the truth, I could not clearly see the differences. I would like to know if there are differences or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. If the nose landing gear (NLG) makes contact first, but the plane settles down on the runway, that's a nose-down landing.
2. If the landing is normal, i.e. the main landing gear (MLG) touches down first, but the plane bounces, only to settle down on the MLG, that's a bounced landing.
3. If the plane bounces, after scenarios 1 or 2, but proceeds to land on the NLG, leading to multiple bounces on the NLG, that's a porpoise landing. Risking structural failure.

[image]

Source: [boldmethod.com](http://www.boldmethod.com/blog/2014/01/the-danger-of-porpoise-landings/)

Comment: A porpoise landing doesn't necessarily have to break something for it to be called a "porpoise", but the timeline you posted shows how it can get out of control quickly.